# Adding a Battery to a Clock and the Probability of Having the Time Be Exactly Correct

Tags: probability

OK, this is probably basic for probability gurus; but, I just grabbed a cheap wall clock from Target, brought it home, and went to put it on the wall--having to add one AA battery before hanging it, of course.

Well, when I went to change the time, I noticed that it was exactly 2:03PM on my cell phone and exactly 2:03PM on the wall clock. Moreover, when the phone switched to 2:04, the second hand was at 2:03:59 . . .!

Shocked so much by how crazy that was, I had to dig through the trash to find the packaging to make sure it wasn't some kind of satellite-linked clock--sure enough, just a $12 P.O.S. clock from Target.

Anyway, my question is, seriously, "What's the probability of something like that happening?" Or, put more simply, what's the probability that when you add a battery to a clock, it'll be set to the same time that it actually IS? (Keep in mind this is a 12 hour wall clock; so, there's no way to say for certain that it was AM or PM just looking at the clock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of being the right hour is $\frac 1{12}$ of being the right minute $\frac 1{60}$ and of being the right second $\frac 1{60}$

So the total probability of switching on the clock at the exact second of another timepiece (disregarding AM/PM) would be $\frac 1{60 * 60 * 12} = \frac 1{43200}$

But, this is assuming that the probability density of each is randomly distributed. That is a pretty big assumption.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :D

Comment: On your point about the random distribution... are you saying that because the clocks are both probably fairly non-precise, that the distribution of seconds, mins, and hours isn't random? Can you explain that point a bit more for me? (Please and thanks!)

Comment: actually I have been wondering about the coincidence after posting the answer. You would think that the manufacturer would set all clocks to a default of 12AM, I am wondering what circumstances led to the clock being set to such a specific time.

Comment: Well, at first I figured it was magic... but, not believing in magic, I figured it was just random... then I wondered *how* random, which brought me here.

Comment: That kind of touches on what I was saying. If the manufactured default is 12AM then the probability distribution of being anything other than precisely 12AM is zero. If, somehow, there was another battery that kept the clock up to date on the shelves, then the probability of a match would be much higher (although not exact, most timepieces we interact with disagree for many reasons).

Comment: Also, you could argue that the probability density is not randomly distributed since it is not equally likely to add the battery at any moment of the day (since e.g. you have to be awake to do that).

Comment: The probability density of when you are adding the battery is not uniformly distributed, no. But if the probability distribution of where the clock is set to is uniform, and you wanted to add the battery at 3:05:28AM you will have the same chance as if you set it at 12:11:57PM. Way to invert the problem though. The fun part is when you have  non-uniform distributions for both the time the user adds the battery and what time the clock is set to. That is a bit out of scope though.

Answer (score 2):

The question is "What's the probability of something like that happening?" and thus should be answered under the appropriate scope of "something like that".

By a conservative estimate, each of the $7$ billion people on Earth on average hangs up one wall clock in their life, which lasts approximately $3$ billion seconds. Thus, roughly $2$ people are hanging up a wall clock per second. If a day has $n$ seconds, that makes $2n$ people per day.

As derived in the other answers, the probability of accidentally starting a $12$-hour wall clock exactly set to the right second is $2/n$. The probability that none of the $2n$ people start the clock exactly on the right second is thus

$$
\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{2n}\approx\mathrm e^{-4}\approx2\%\;.
$$

Already for a single day, this is quite unlikely. Over the course of, say, a year, it becomes extremely unlikely. The expected number of people who set their wall clocks exactly right over the course of a year is roughly

$$
365\cdot2n\cdot\frac2n=1460\;.
$$

math.SE has been around for five years, so over the course of its existence roughly $7300$ people have set their wall clocks exactly to the right second by accident. It was only a matter of time (pun intended) until one of them would find their way here and ask this question.

Comment: Haha! This is wonderful. :) Thank you joriki!!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are $12 \times 60 \times 60 = 43200$ seconds per 12 hours the probability it was set to the very same second is $1/43200\approx 0.0023$ %. If it was exact to 1/10th second then the probability drops by 1/10.

Comment: Thanks for the point about 1/10th of a second accuracy!

Comment: You are welcome. Typing on the phone is probably too slow for stackexchange :) Thanks for the upvote.